# HTML/CSS repetitive + image header

Tags: html, css

I got a header working but in a very ugly way, can someone please tell me the nice way to do this?

I want to have an infinite header, with an image in the center. So I need to have a repetitive background-image, then put my image, and then continue the infinite image. I also have to do the infinite line below the image. Here is my working but ugly HTML code:

```
<h1>
    <div align="center">
        <img src="designs/header12.png" align="center"/>
    </div>
</h1>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<h2></h2>
```

I had to put a series of `<br/>` to be able to put h2 in the correct position. This is how h1 and h2 look like in the CSS:

```
h1 {
    background:url('../designs/headerPiece.png');
    height: 33px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
h2 {
    background:url('../designs/headerPiece.png');
    height: 33px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I give the image as a background to a h1, this way you can write on it and that's more SEO friendly. In this case you have to give the dimensions to the h1 of the background (width and height properties).

The HTML:

```
<div id="page">
  <h1 id="header"> </h1>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#page {
  background: url('../designs/headerPiece.png') top left repeat-x;
}

#page h1 { 
 background: url('designs/header12.png') top left no-repeat;
 margin: 0px auto;
 width: width-of-the-header;
 height: 33px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<div class="background"></div>
<h1><img src="designs/header12.png" align="center"></h1>
<div class="background"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.background {
    background: transparent url('../designs/headerPiece.png') top left repeat-x;
    height: 33px;
    width: 100%;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, however I'm missing the bottom piece in your code... I need another repeat-x background image on the bottom of that header, and that's what I don't know how to put correctly.

Comment: I've edited the answer taking into account the second heading. However, if they are really the same image headerPiece.png you could make the height 66px, then replace repeat-x for repeat and you wouldn't need h2. If you have a live version please share.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a live version... The problem is that they don't have to be together... It has to look like this:   |o|    (rotate that 90 degrees). The 'o' would be header12.png and the '|' headerPiece.png... Thanks for trying to understand :)